# How to launch a gnome-terminal from Python without it being root?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I am writing a python script that requires root privileges to run, and I want to launch a gnome-terminal, but when I do it launches it as root, which is a safety hazard. Is there any way I can launch the terminal as normal user in Ubuntu?

My command looks like this

```
os.system("gnome-terminal")
```

Comment: Use `os.setuid()` to revert back to the original userid.

Comment: How should I use that command exactly? Just before I use os.system?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but that sounds right. Then call it again to go back to root.

Comment: You might need to use `os.seteuid()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230467/unable-to-switch-back-to-root-user-using-python/14475934#14475934 for example

Comment: I tried os.setuid() just before os.system() but it didn't open a terminal. It also wouldn't let me turn back to root

Comment: Did you read the question I linked to? You have to use `seteuid()` if you want to be able to go back.

Comment: I did see it, but when I use os.seteuid(), it still launches the terminal as root, which is not what I need

Comment: How are you running the script as root? If you're using `sudo`, it probably clears out environment variables that are needed to open the terminal window properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252704/discussion-between-aerialsong-and-barmar).